# How to handle big fractions?

Tags: java, fractions

I need to do math on big fractions, so in addition for example, I need to have same denumerator, multiplying these big fractions makes them go over long(java) type limit. Using float or double seems to be not percise enough. What can i do?

I tried using float and I failed.

Comment: Use `BigInteger` and/or `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Or, if you can use libraries, there's a ready-to-use [`BigFraction`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-numbers/commons-numbers-docs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/numbers/fraction/BigFraction.html) from [Apache Commons Numbers](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-numbers/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use inbuild BigInteger or String or integer array to store java. For any reference view this page.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number/